# How to obtain the authenticity token given the session and the devise secret key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise

How to obtain the authenticity token given the session and the secret key?

I'm using rails and devise.
I want to logout from a webview on a iOS app, but I get this error:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

So I'm planning to obtain the token from the session cookie and using the secret key. It might not be a good idea to ship the app with the secret key on the code, but I'm just planning to do it for a prototype. (How should I do it without using the secret key?)

**Better solution**

If you have access to the session via the cookies, you probably have access to the meta tags of the html, so you can easily retrieve the authenticity_token with this jquery:

```
$('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the session via the cookies, you probably have access to the meta tags of the html, so you can easily retrieve the authenticity_token with this jquery:

```
$('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions here.

First, if you're not using form_for or form_tag, I'd recommend using those. If you can't for some reason, it may be a better idea to just turn off CSRF protection for the controller/method by setting

```
protect_from_forgery except :my_method_i_dont_want_protection_on
```

in your controller file. Not recommended though. Any reason you can't just use the form helpers that will include it for you?

Comment: I'm doing a wrapper; We have a rails app which is responsive, so we are planning to wrap it in a iOS WebView based app while we work on a native app. However, there is some stuff that doesn't display correctly, 1 of those things is the logout stuff, so I'm planning to create the request for the logout with objective-c  and make the webview to process it, BUT rails detects this as a potential CSRF (because someone set 'DELETE' as the http method for the logout path). Rails says: 'Can't verify CSRF...' and I notice that my custom request lacks the authenticity_token.

Comment: inspecting the DOM, I see the authenticity token in a meta tag. I'll try to include it on my custom request and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

i think u r looking for this `form_authenticity_token`

[See this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f4fdd643f9d19fbbeeec3ac77674f791c9beffa/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L249)